# Орг-вопрос к завсегдатаям ресурса.

Tags: общие-вопросы, другое

Здравствуйте, товарищи аксакалы! :)

Я тут "на новеньких" и не могу понять такой момент: **чем участие в «исследовании» отличается от обычного ответа на вопрос?
Кем и как проводится это разграничение?**

По тому, как составлены темы исследований (которые успела просмотреть), обнаружить явные отличия мне не удалось... Ощущение, что некоторым вопросам произвольно дано иное оформление.

Да и почему на страницах «исследований» не предусмотрена форма для ответа? – тоже не понятно...

Заранее благодарю за корректные разъяснения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле, исследования предполагают не просто вопрос "почему так", а детальное изложение своей точки зрения, анализ какого-либо вопроса.
Но этот раздел еще находится в стадии разработки.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик!
Не могли бы Вы пояснить, почему вот ЭТО помещено в "исследования"?
http://russ.hashcode.ru/research/32737/%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%85-%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%85

Пыталась дать свою версию в формате "встречного мнения", мне рекомендовали оформить мнение как ответ на вопрос.

Хотя я писала не столько чёткий ответ, как размышление на заданную тему...

Answer (score 2):

Если  вы  произведёте  исследование  вопроса,  изложите  его  и  сделаете  вывод,  то  эту  конечную  часть  исследования  можно  назвать  ответом.  Если  вы  ознакомите  нас,  как  вы  к  этому  выводу  пришли,  то  это  уже  исследование.